# java ArrayList with Byte Array : ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type error

Tags: java

I am trying to add a byte array in arraylist of bytearrays.

Code:

```
    ArrayList<Byte []> bArrayList = new ArrayList<Byte[]>();
    byte[] onekVideofile= new byte[1024];
    in.read(onekVideofile, 0, 1024);
    bArrayList.add(onekVideofile);

    Error: 
    bArrayList cannot be resolved to a type
  - The method add(Byte[]) in the type ArrayList<Byte[]> is not applicable for the   arguments 
 (byte[])
```

Not sure why its giving error when all three are of type byte array.
Thanks for your time and input,

Comment: Byte[] and byte[] are not the same

Comment: Byte[] onekVideofile = new Byte[1024]

Comment: why not use `ArrayList<byte[]> bArrayList`?

Comment: Thank you guys. understood and corrected.

Answer (score 2):

First, `byte` is not the same as `Byte`. They are different types. Your `ArrayList` expects a `Byte[]` but you are handing it a `byte[]`.

Second, this error message

```
bArrayList cannot be resolved to a type
```

seems to indicate that you are invoking

```
bArrayList.add(onekVideofile);
```

in the class body. You cannot put statements (method invocations and the like) directly in a class body, you can only put declarations. Put it in a constructor or method body.

Comment: Great catch -- yes that would have to be the context. Another error.

Answer (score 1):

Although a `byte` can be auto-boxed into `Byte`, so that you can pass a `byte` to a method accepting `Byte`, the same is not true of arrays. A `byte[]` can't be passed to an argument accepting `Byte[]`. Without auto-boxing, they are of course of quite different types and are not otherwise assignable from each other.